# How to plot Riemann zeta function in xy coordinate system?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Riemann zeta function in complex plane would look like[image] 
  How to plot this curve best as piece wise functions against x-axis in xy plane.

Comment: As @reuns indicated in the answer below, the x and y axes represent the real and imaginary parts of $\zeta\left(\frac {1}{2}+i\,t\right)$ for $0\le t\le 35 $ which begins at $\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,0 \right) = -1.46035$ and ends at $\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,35\right)=2.60034\,+1.10779\,i$. Since the input and output with (respect to the zeta function) are both generally complex numbers, your question about how to plot the graph without using complex numbers seems misguided.

Comment: Here's what I did to plot the graph: https://www.geogebra.org/m/T47QECTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the question is but this famous misleading plot is [the curve $\zeta(1/2+it),t\in [0,35]$ in the complex plane](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7BReal%5BZeta%5B1%2F2%2BI*u%5D%5D%2CImag%5BZeta%5B1%2F2%2BI*u%5D%5D%7D%2C+%7Bu%2C+0%2C+30%7D%5D).

Comment: Impossible to guess what you mean with "without using complex numbers". It is the Riemann zeta function, you need complex numbers just to define its values on $\Re(s)=1/2$ (by analytic continuation)